# Android Studio previously running app does not run

Tags: linux, ubuntu, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 1.2.1.1 on Ubuntu OS
while debugging an app the run button stops relaunching the app.

I noticed that on the run console [next to the android and TODO consoles] the each launch causes another app to start.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I can solve this problem by

1. stopping all the apps
2. detaching and reattaching the device
3. relaunching the app

Other times relaunching Android Studio helps

I would gladly endorse a better less speculative answer